# Angular 1 custom directive not executing

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-directive

I have my directive defined as follows:

```
'use strict;'

angular.module('clientApp')

.directive('afterLast', ['$ocLazyLoad','$timeout',function($ocLazyLoad, $timeout){
    console.log('entered directive');
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, elem, attr){
            if (scope.$last === true){
                console.log('entered directive')
                $timeout(function(){
                    $ocLazyLoad.load(['some files'])   
                })
            }
        }
    }
}]);
```

And, I am using it as an attribute as follows:

```
<div ng-repeat="topicObject in module.topics track by $index" afterLast>

  <div class="ft-section">

    <div ng-repeat="learningPointObject in topicObject.learningPoints track by $index">
        <div class="ft-page">
            <h2 class="module-name" style="text-align: center;">{{module.name | capitalize:true}}</h2>
            <h3 class="topic-name">{{topicObject.name | capitalize:true}}</h3>
            <h4>{{learningPointObject.name | capitalize}}</h4>
            <hr>
         </div>
     </div>

  </div>

</div>
```

But my directive is not executing. Even the console.log statements inside and outside the link function are not working.
1. Am I using directives the correct way?
2. If yes, what could be the reasons for it not working?

Comment: In the HTML element, your directive is referred to by `after-last`, not `afterLast`

Comment: yes, this was what I had missed. Thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the HTML the directive name needs to be in kebab-case, not camelCase.

```
 <!-- ERRONEOUS camelCase
 <div ng-repeat="topicObject in module.topics track by $index" afterLast>
 -->

 <!-- USE kebab-case -->
 <div ng-repeat="topicObject in module.topics track by $index" after-last>
```

For more information, see [AngularJS Developer Guide - Directive Normalization](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive#normalization)

Answer (score 0):

directive : for last watch of ng-repeat..
app.directive('afterLast',function(){
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {},
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            if (attrs.ngRepeat) {
                if (scope.$parent.$last) {
                    if (attrs.afterLast !== '') {
                        if (typeof scope.$parent.$parent[attrs.afterLast] === 'function') {
                            // Executes defined function
                            scope.$parent.$parentattrs.afterLast;
                        } else {
                            // For watcher, if you prefer
                            scope.$parent.$parent[attrs.afterLast] = true;
                        }
                    }
                }
            } else {
                throw 'ngRepeatEndWatch: `ngRepeat` Directive required to use this Directive';
            }
        }
    }
});

function call on last call

$scope.layoutDone = function () {

you want your desire data here

}

html

{{module.name | capitalize:true}}
            {{topicObject.name | capitalize:true}}
            {{learningPointObject.name | capitalize}}

---